# How can I properly plot this region, with some filling too?

Tags: plotting, regions, filling

I have to plot this region:

$$A = \{(x, y)\in [0, 2]\times [0, 1]; x+y \leq 2\}$$

Here is what I did:

```
Plot[{2 - x, 1}, {x, 0, 2},
Epilog -> {Orange, Line[{{2, 0}, {2, 1}}], Thickness[0.04]}]
```

The result is efficient, but yucky. Efficient because with the proper equation aside one can see which region we are talking about. Yucky because I would like the lines to have the same colour, and the region (the quadrilateral) to be filled with some pastel colour (like a light green).

How can I do it?

[image: output from plot]

Comment: Why don't you use [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) and [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html)? ``RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x + y <= 2 && 0 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}]]``

Comment: @Domen Because it just shows the quadrilateral, and it's not what I want

Comment: Something like this? `Plot[{2 - x, 1}, {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}
 , PlotStyle -> Black]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Plot[{2 - x, 1, Min[2 - x, 1]}, {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {3 -> 0}, 
 Exclusions -> None, 
 Epilog -> {Orange, Line[{{2, 0}, {2, 1}}], Thickness[0.04]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Combine [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html), [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) and [`Rectangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html) by using [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html).

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[
  ImplicitRegion[x + y <= 2 && 0 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}], 
  PlotStyle -> LightGreen, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0.05],
 Plot[2 - x, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thick],
 Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[{Thick, ColorData[97][2]}], 
   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

Plot[{Min[2 - x, 1],
  Tooltip[2 - x, y == 2 - x],
  Tooltip[1, y == 1]},
 {x, 0, 2},
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1],
 Filling -> 1 -> Axis,
 Epilog -> {ColorData[97][1],
   AbsoluteThickness[1.5], Line[{{2, 0}, {2, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
rectangle = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}];

Plot[2 - x, {x, 0, 2},
 Filling -> {1 -> {1, White}},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotStyle -> Thick,
 Prolog -> {LightGreen, rectangle},
 Epilog -> {EdgeForm[{Thick, Orange}], FaceForm[], rectangle}]
```

[image]